# What is the shell mode started with the apostrophe?

Tags: shell

In a (SSH) terminal session, what is the purpose of the mode started by the key sequence `apostrophe <ENTER>` or more literally `'<ENTER>`.

What is the way to exit that mode?

Comment: You mean that you type `'` then enter, and are wondering what's happening?

Comment: Yes. I will edit to clarify.

Comment: There actually is a "special SSH command mode" that is started by default `~` followed by newline. See the "Escape characters" section in `man ssh`. I'm guessing this is not what you are seeing here, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typing <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd> doesn't start any special SSH mode. The (normal) commands you type are interpreted by the shell on the other end of your SSH connection, not SSH itself.

<kbd>'</kbd> is usually called a single quote in shell terminology, <kbd>"</kbd> a double-quote, and <kbd>`</kbd> is a backtick.

<kbd>'</kbd> starts a character sequence that is not interpreted by the shell. This is useful, for example, if you need to pass and argument to a program the must contain `$` or another character sequence the would otherwise be interpreted by the shell, or that contains newlines. You end that sequence with another <kbd>'</kbd>.

<kbd>"</kbd> is similar, but some interpolation happens (i.e. variables are expanded).

<kbd>`</kbd> is different. That's for command substitution. If you type

```
echo `foo`
```

the output of running the `foo` program is substituted before running the `echo` command. Another way of doing that is by using `$(...)`:

```
echo $(foo)
```

So if you type <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd>, you're just starting a multiline literal string. You end that either with a matching <kbd>'</kbd>, or with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> if you want to break out.

```
$ echo 'hello
> this
> is 
> a
> multiline
> string
> '
hello
this
is
a
multiline
string
$ echo 'foo $PWD'
foo $PWD               # no interpolation
$ echo "foo $PWD"
foo /tmp               # interpolation
```

Starting a line with a `'` isn't really useful by itself.